# Store data from duplicated fields into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Hy everyone, i had two fields like this and later i needed to repeat those fields so i did that with JavaScript like this

```
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{Form::label('_customer_name', 'Customer Name :', ['class' => 'contc p-4 icn']) }}
                            {{Form::email( '_customer_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control chos_bsns', 'id' => '_customer_name', 'placeholder' => 'eMail here ']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">

                            {{sprintf(Form::label('_feedback', '%s',['class' => 'compny_over icn']),'Feedback recieved from customer &nbsp;&nbsp;<small>( Maximum 100 words )</small>
                            <span> Word Count : 6 </span>') }}
                            {{Form::textarea( '_Feedback', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => '_feedback', 'placeholder' => 'Information regarding service' , 'rows' => '5']) }}
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

and i was submitting the values in the data base like this earlier

```
[
  'name'=>Input::get('_customer_name'),
  'feedback'=>Input::get('_Feedback'),
  'website_id'=>Input::get('website_id')             
];
Testimonial::create($data);
```

but since i repeated it i dont know to store those in the database any ideas would be much help.

Comment: You're saying, you have 2 forms, that store the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [] to all fields which are dynamic (So created with Javascript) So you will send an Array of values to Laravel. For example:

```
name="customer_name[]"
```

Then you can check for values with:

```
$c = count($request->customer_name[]);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    // add new customer
}
```

Comment: i did that and i was getting an array now if i dump it like this.


`$emails = Request::get('_customer_name');`

`dd($emails);`

Comment: So and whats the problem now? You can loop through the array and store all values

Comment: i do get an array like this
`array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "test@email.com" [1]=> string(15) "test1@email.com" } array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "1st feedback" [1]=> string(12) "2nd feedback" }` 

in which test@email.com gives the feedback value which is "1st feedback" and similarly the test1@email.com submits the value 2nd feedback.

Comment: ? I dont understand your problem. Ok youre getting now an array of fields, and could loop over every field to store a new model in your database. Read out your field data in the for loop, with  $request->customer_name[$i]

Answer (score 0):

this works if we have the same no of fields. :)

```
for($ii = 0; $ii < count($emails) ; $ii++) {
$email = $emails[$ii];
$feedback = $feedbacks[$ii];
Testimonial::create([
    'name' => $email,
    'feedback'=>$feedback,
    'website_id'=>Input::get('website_id')
]);}
```